# Compile and publish only part of Angular application

Tags: angular, enterprise

I'm working on an angular enterprise application, and I have quite serious problem: When I need to update one of my pages, I need to re-compile the whole application and then copy it to all customers.
It takes lot of time, and even worse, the compilation might fault because of another page, that because of some reason has compilation error.
It's very dangerous and could be tiring when you have hundreds pages in your app, 
it's very bad way to for doing updates..

I'm expected a way for compile only single page (actually it's a lazy loaded module - and I can do it by set this module as the only route), and 
after that - update the relevant files (eg inline.js & main.js) - even manually - for the change.

Any help? I guess that this problem is very common in the enterprise world..
Thank you

Comment: Cant you use feature brances to develop new features? Then you deploy whatever feature when you want

Comment: For develop it's not a problem, the problem is when I need to publish the change

Comment: I have the same question, In 2020, there still are some stuff use IE, I can't use web-component, any solution? I want to use iframe haha :)))

Comment: I have the same question but for DURING development. If I'm working on section D of my app, I don't need A, B, C compiled every time I run ng serve. I want my *initial* ng serve to be as fast as possible - I'm working on section D for a month. I don't want to compile the rest!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Angular CLI, you should note that All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking (More details on this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling--tree-shaking)).

What I recommend doing is keep the production version in one branch. Then, when you want to deploy new stuff, you merge only the changes you need. This should ensure no compilation errors, and if there are errors it means you either didn't merge all the changes you need or there is a bug.

Another way you can try to deal with this is to create separate modules in different library projects that the main app will consume (as you do with 3rd party libraries). Then you could compile and replace only a specific module library.
More on that [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 
I agree that it's possible, but it's not streight forward.. Comparing to deploy c# project for example, that you need only compile single dll and copy this single file to the client. But thank a lot

Comment: @Itiel a C# dll is a library project which is just like the 2nd suggestion I made.

Comment: In your second suggestion - Is the cli generate seaperate chunk for the library? I'm assume that it's not the case..

Comment: The library is a separate project that you need to build separately. However, when you consume it in your application it will be bundled like everything else. There might be a way to deal with that, but I never had to do something like this before.